# SDL and zlib issue, cannot create valid rwops structure from zip

Tags: c++, sdl, zlib

I have been trying to read a zip archive and load a png image from it, however i am getting not valid image format error from SDL_Image. Here is the code

```
#include <SDL\SDL.h>
#include <SDL\SDL_opengl.h>
#include <SDL\SDL_image.h>

#define ZLIB_WINAPI //to use zlibwapi dll
#include <zlib.h>
#include <zip.h> //minizip
#include <unzip.h> //minizip

#include <string>

SDL_RWops* readfromarchive(std::string archive, std::string filename)
{

unzFile data;
unz_file_info   info;
Uint8*  buffer = NULL;
SDL_RWops* rw = NULL;

data = unzOpen(archive.c_str());
unzLocateFile( data, filename.c_str(), 1 );
unzGetCurrentFileInfo( data, &info, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0 );
unzOpenCurrentFile( data );
buffer = (Uint8*)malloc(info.uncompressed_size);
unzReadCurrentFile( data, buffer, info.uncompressed_size );
rw = SDL_RWFromMem(buffer, info.uncompressed_size);
free(buffer);
unzClose(data);
return rw;
}
```

when i do this

```
    Surf_Temp = IMG_Load_RW( readfromarchive(archive, filename) , 1);
```

I get the error IMG_Load_RW: %s Unsupported image format
Well, if load directly from the unzipped file it works using IMG_Load(), works when create a rwops structure through sdl and load too using

```
    IMG_Load_RW(SDL_RWFromFile(filename.c_str(), "rb"), 1);
```

So the file format is fine, all zlib and minizip functions dont return any error, i check the info struct and the data is consistant with the file i am trying to load, so the error is somewhere in creating the rwops struct.

Comment: What is the result of `unzLocateFile`?

Comment: its UNZ_OK, results till unzReadCurrentFile are all okay, even SDL_RWFromMem return a non null rwops structure, but IMG_Load_RW doesnt think its valid... :(

Comment: Also, how about save the buffer to disk and see if a proper images comes out. Also if you know that is is for example a PNG, try if it works with IMG_LoadPNG_RW.

Comment: Ignore me, I think I got it... answer in 30 sec....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the following. You are using an RWOPs structure form SDL. In the given case you want to read from memory. **But you delete the memory before your read it.** The RWOPs structure will not copy the memory, it needs to remain valid until everything is read.

To solve the problem, pull the call to `IMG_Load_RW` before the call to `free(buffer);`

Comment: I feel so stupid, i had assumed that the buffer is copied to the rwops structure, i am guessing rwops just points to the buffer with additional information for sdl... well i am at work now, i cant try it right now, will go home and check, thanks